# Shiny renderDataTable | how to limit text size displayed

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

While displaying a data table in shiny

```
output$tab1 <- renderDataTable({
expr = tbl
}, options = list(orderClasses = TRUE,
                  lengthMenu = c(3, 5, 10),
                  pageLength = 3)
```

I would like to limit the text in each cell to 30 characters. Is there an option for that in order to facilitate the reading?

I tried the solution of package DT (http://rstudio.github.io/DT/, see section 2.5.4 column rendering) but I was unsuccessful (I want to use renderDataTable with my current list of options)

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Regards,

Thomas

Comment: Maybe you can test for character length with nchar for the columns that exceed your limit of 30 characters?

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if you still looking for the answer. But, it is pretty easy to include a tool tip using the example below. 
You can find this example and more in this link 
https://rstudio.github.io/DT/options.html

```
datatable(iris[c(1:20, 51:60, 101:120), ], options = list(columnDefs = list(list(
  targets = 5,
  render = JS(
    "function(data, type, row, meta) {",
    "return type === 'display' && data.length > 6 ?",
    "'<span title=\"' + data + '\">' + data.substr(0, 6) + '...</span>' : data;",
    "}")
))), callback = JS('table.page(3).draw(false);'))
```

Comment: what does that `targets=5` mean here? how it can be used?

Comment: `targets` parameter is for specifying which column you would like the function to be applied. In the above case, we are limiting the text size displayed in column 5, and rendering a tooltip.

Comment: Got it. Just one confusion. columns are only those columns which contains text or strings, or are all the columns? supposing that in a reactive dataset, the last column is the one on which truncation of text is to be performed, then how one can do that?

Comment: if you have a `df` with 5 columns and you like to apply tooltip ( shown in the above example) on columns 2, 3, & 5. you set `targets = c(2,3,5)`.  If you just want last column ( here is it column 5), then just  `targets = 5`

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to mutate your column to shorten any strings with more than 30 characters.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

tbl <- tbl %>% mutate(column_name = as.character(column_name)) %>% 
               rowwise() %>% 
               mutate(column_name = case_when(nchar(column_name) > 30 ~
               paste(str_sub(column_name, 1, 30), "..."),
               nchar(column_name) <= 30 ~ column_name))
```

This will shorten all strings to 30 characters and add a ... at the end.