# Rendering datatable in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have this table which contains some fields with a huge text, like abstracts, and when i render them it looks terrible.

is there a way to show only part of the text, with the "`...`"?

Like:

```
id;name;author;abstract
123;Lucca;Adam;"Abstract text..."
```

Here's an image of how it looks like:

**Data Table :**

[image: Data Table]

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28693738/shiny-renderdatatable-how-to-limit-text-size-displayed

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I've tried a code suggested but it kept stuck with the message "processing" and it didn't do it =/

Comment: It works fine for me, I will add an example.

Comment: You could try the ellipsis plugin: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52022957/display-cell-value-in-tooltip-after-hovering-over-a-cell-in-dtdatatable/53722565#53722565

Answer (score 0):

As mention in the comments, based on [Shiny renderDataTable | how to limit text size displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28693738/shiny-renderdatatable-how-to-limit-text-size-displayed), you can achieve it:

```
# generating new variable in iris dataset with 5000 characters per row
iris$text <- apply(iris, 1, function(x) {paste0(letters[sample(26,5000,T)],collapse = "")})
# increasing the volume of data to 15K rows
iris <- do.call("rbind", replicate(100, iris, simplify = FALSE))

# Shiny app example
library(shiny)
library(DT)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      column(12,
             dataTableOutput('table')
      )
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$table <- renderDataTable(iris,
                                    options = list(columnDefs = list(list(
                                      targets = 6,
                                      render = JS(
                                        "function(data, type, row, meta) {",
                                        "return type === 'display' && data.length > 6 ?",
                                        "'<span title=\"' + data + '\">' + data.substr(0, 6) + '...</span>' : data;",
                                        "}")
                                    ))), callback = JS('table.page(3).draw(false);'))
  }
)
```

Comment: Yes, i've managed to do that! But it only works with columns with small info... when i set `target=(hugetextcolumn)` it shows an empty table and it also takes a lot of time to run the code... i wonder what happened =/