# Display cell value in tooltip after hovering over a cell in DT::datatable

Tags: javascript, r, datatables, shiny, dt

How do I utilize javascript to display the cell value in a tooltip after hovering over a particular cell in a DT::datatable? I decided to hide the long text after a certain width is reached (`overflow-x: hidden; white-space: nowrap;`) to maintain a clean format, and I would like the user to be able to see the full text if they choose to hover over a given cell.

```
datatable(df,
          class="compact",
          selection="none",
          rownames=F,
          colnames=NULL,
          options=list(dom="t",
                       pageLength=10
          ),
          escape=F)
```

Comment: Could you provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try this:

```r
datatable(head(iris), 
          options=list(initComplete = JS(
            "function(settings) {
            var table=settings.oInstance.api();
            table.$('td').each(function(){
              this.setAttribute('title', $(this).html())
              })
            }")))
```

This sets a tooltip for every cell.

To set the tooltip for a single specific cell:

```r
datatable(head(iris), 
          options=list(initComplete = JS(
            "function(settings) {
            var table = settings.oInstance.api();
            var cell = table.cell(2,2);
            cell.node().setAttribute('title', cell.data());
            }")))
```

Comment: Yes, the first solution is it! That provides a way for the user to hover over a cell and see its full value as a tooltip. It comes in handy with columns that contain very large/long values; I can keep my table more compact by hiding excess characters and allowing users to see full values (if necessary) with the tooltip.

Comment: @DaleKube FYI, the plugin [ellipsis](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/dataRender/ellipsis) is now available in the new version of `DT`. I have not tried yet but it seems to be useful for your problem.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent thanks a lot! Could you please suggest a code that would put such a hint only for certain columns, or (even better), ignore all html inserts and tags (for example, link or symbols)

Comment: @Avraam With the **ellipsis** plugin you can select the columns you want.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Unfortunately, ellipsis plugin is unfinished.
Problem 1: I need to set ellipsis not based on the absolutely set value in R, but on the current width of the table of contents (preferably with a minimum value)
Problem 2: It incorrectly cuts cells with url links and other html addins

Your version is better than that plugin. But I would like to finalize it.

Comment: @Avraam Then open a new question please.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent done. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75114938 - I tried to draw a reproducible example and my attempts to find a solution

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution with the newly available plugin **ellipsis**.

```
library(DT) # version 0.5

dat <- data.frame(
  A = c("fnufnufroufrcnoonfrncacfnouafc", "fanunfrpn frnpncfrurnucfrnupfenc"),
  B = c("DZDOPCDNAL DKODKPODPOKKPODZKPO", "AZERTYUIOPQSDFGHJKLMWXCVBN")
)

datatable(
  dat, 
  plugins = "ellipsis",
  options = list(
    columnDefs = list(list(
      targets = c(1,2),
      render = JS("$.fn.dataTable.render.ellipsis( 17, false )")
    ))
  )
)
```

[image]

Documentation of the plugin: https://datatables.net/plug-ins/dataRender/ellipsis

Comment: This is great. Thank you!