# Implementation of ellipsis overflow and tooltip when hovering over the cell for r datatable

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, datatables, dt

## Axiomatics:

1. There is a multi-column table, the cells may contain very long text
2. Some columns may contain either short text, long text, or a url link
3. wrap - inconvenient. The rows must be the same size. Therefore, it does not fit
4. scroll - inconvenient

---

## Expected solution:

Through a bunch of responsive (collapse of non-fitting columns into rows) + Buttons(colvis) (the ability to remove extra columns).

---

## Example

Here is an example of such a raw table for layout:

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(data.table)

shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(dataTableOutput('tbl')),
    server = function(input, output) {
        output$tbl = renderDataTable(
            datatable(
                data.table(
                    col1 = c('asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd', 'alotlotlotlotalotlotlotlotalotlotlotlot', 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'),
                    col2 = c('asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd', 'alotlotlotlotalotlotlotlotalotlotlotlot', 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'),
                    col3 = c('this is url', 'alotlotlotlotalotlotlotlotalotlotlotlot', 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'),
                    col4 = c('asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd', 'alotlotlotlotalotlotlotlotalotlotlotlot', 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'),
                    col5 = c('asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd', 'alotlotlotlotalotlotlotlotalotlotlotlot', 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'),
                    col6 = c('asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd', 'alotlotlotlotalotlotlotlotalotlotlotlot', 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'),
                    col7 = c('asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd', 'alotlotlotlotalotlotlotlotalotlotlotlot', 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'),
                    col8 = c('asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd', 'alotlotlotlotalotlotlotlotalotlotlotlot', 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'),
                    col9 = c('asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd', 'alotlotlotlotalotlotlotlotalotlotlotlotalotlotlotlotalotlotlotlotalotlotlotlotalotlotlotlotalotlotlotlotalotlotlotlotalotlotlotlotalotlotlotlotalotlotlotlot', 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'),
                    col_link = c('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page', 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page', 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page')
                ) %>%
                    .[col3 == 'this is url link long',
                      col3 := sprintf(paste0(
                          "<a href=\"%s\" target=\"_blank\" style=\"color:blue\" onmouseover=\"style='",
                          "text-decoration:underline; color:darkblue'\" onmouseout=\"style='",
                          "text-decoration:none; color:blue'\" >%s</a>"), col_link, col3)],
                plugins      = 'ellipsis',
                extensions   = c('Responsive', 'Buttons'),
                escape       = FALSE,
                selection    = 'none',
                options = list(
                    dom        = 'Blftip',
                    pageLength = 3,
                    lengthMenu = c(1, 3),
                    buttons    = I('colvis'),
                    columnDefs = list(
                        list(
                            targets = c('col1', 'col2', 'col4', 'col9'),
                            render  = JS("$.fn.dataTable.render.ellipsis(10)"))))))})
```

---

## Problems

What is the problem with the implementation:

1. cell values that are too long should be shortened using ellipsis

   - The number of non-hidden characters should be set dynamically based on the page size and the number of columns (and their width), and not a pre-fixed value
2. When hovering over a cell:

   - the full contents should be revealed
   - only for collapsed lines via ellipsis
   - should ignore HTML inserts
   - should work in the collapsed version via responsive for very long lines
   - There are a lot of lines, so pagination, js filters datatable should work and not break ellipsis with tooltips and responsive
3. An independent column switch has been implemented, which allows you to: delete/add columns + change their sorting, so a column can be either collapsed or expanded in a group. And there is also a large left sidebar that also changes the width of the table. Accordingly, it should be taken into account that the column can be anywhere.

What else is needed ideally (but with a separate request):

4. fully resizable when the column goes exactly with the mouse. If a column collapses to the table border, all subsequent columns move down to the responsive in collapse. The minimum value is ~10 pixels per column

---

## Possible solutions found

I found two partial solutions on the Internet

1. ellipsis plugin
2. The solution based on [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52022957/display-cell-value-in-tooltip-after-hovering-over-a-cell-in-dtdatatable/52170239?noredirect=1#comment132499460_52170239) to the github from Laurent (thank you!)

Unfortunately, these options do not fit perfectly into the raw table above

I would like to see suggestions on how to finalize it - any of them, or my own additional one.

### Case I: Ellipsis

Problems:

1. The text of the "collapsed" columns is reduced, for which the width has become much larger relative to the first columns that did not fall under the collapse
2. If you hide the extra columns (all except col1 and col3) and leave only 2, then there is enough space to display the full text, but there is still an unnecessary ellipsis
3. It does not ignore html inclusions (when hovering over a link) - this is important, because there may be a link in the cell, or an ordinary very long text

pic1

[image]

pic2

[image]

```r
shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(dataTableOutput('tbl')),
    server = function(input, output) {
        output$tbl = renderDataTable(
            datatable(
                data.table(
                    col1 = c('asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd', 'alotlotlotlotalotlotlotlotalotlotlotlot', 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'),
                    col2 = c('asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd', 'alotlotlotlotalotlotlotlotalotlotlotlot', 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'),
                    col3 = c('this is url link long', 'alotlotlotlotalotlotlotlotalotlotlotlot', 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'),
                    col4 = c('asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd', 'alotlotlotlotalotlotlotlotalotlotlotlot', 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'),
                    col5 = c('asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd', 'alotlotlotlotalotlotlotlotalotlotlotlot', 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'),
                    col6 = c('asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd', 'alotlotlotlotalotlotlotlotalotlotlotlot', 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'),
                    col7 = c('asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd', 'alotlotlotlotalotlotlotlotalotlotlotlot', 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'),
                    col8 = c('asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd', 'alotlotlotlotalotlotlotlotalotlotlotlot', 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'),
                    col9 = c('asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd', 'alotlotlotlotalotlotlotlotalotlotlotlotalotlotlotlotalotlotlotlotalotlotlotlotalotlotlotlotalotlotlotlotalotlotlotlotalotlotlotlotalotlotlotlotalotlotlotlot', 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'),
                    col_link = c('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page', 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page', 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page')
                ) %>%
                    .[col3 == 'this is url link long',
                      col3 := sprintf(paste0(
                          "<a href=\"%s\" target=\"_blank\" style=\"color:blue\" onmouseover=\"style='",
                          "text-decoration:underline; color:darkblue'\" onmouseout=\"style='",
                          "text-decoration:none; color:blue'\" >%s</a>"), col_link, col3)],
                plugins      = 'ellipsis',
                extensions   = c('Responsive', 'Buttons'),
                selection    = 'none',
                escape       = FALSE,
                options = list(
                    dom        = 'Blftip',
                    pageLength = 3,
                    lengthMenu = c(1, 3),
                    buttons    = I('colvis'),
                    columnDefs = list(
                        list(
                            targets = c('col1', 'col3', 'col5', 'col9'),
                            render  = JS("$.fn.dataTable.render.ellipsis(10)")
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    }
)
```

### Case II: Custom CSS + JS code

Problems:

1. Ellipsis does not work in collapsed form + JS callback too

   [image]
2. The hint display is interrupted when:

   - Switching pages
   - Application of the filter
   - Changing the number of lines per page
   - etc.

   [image]
3. The tooltip does not ignore html inclusions (when hovering the mouse cursor over the link)

   [image]

```r
shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(
        tags$head(
            tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "app.css")
        ),
        dataTableOutput('tbl')),
    server = function(input, output) {
        output$tbl = renderDataTable(
            datatable(
                data.table(
                    col1 = c('asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd', 'alotlotlotlotalotlotlotlotalotlotlotlot', 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'),
                    col2 = c('asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd', 'alotlotlotlotalotlotlotlotalotlotlotlot', 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'),
                    col3 = c('this is url link long', 'alotlotlotlotalotlotlotlotalotlotlotlot', 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'),
                    col4 = c('asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd', 'alotlotlotlotalotlotlotlotalotlotlotlot', 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'),
                    col5 = c('asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd', 'alotlotlotlotalotlotlotlotalotlotlotlot', 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'),
                    col6 = c('asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd', 'alotlotlotlotalotlotlotlotalotlotlotlot', 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'),
                    col7 = c('asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd', 'alotlotlotlotalotlotlotlotalotlotlotlot', 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'),
                    col8 = c('asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd', 'alotlotlotlotalotlotlotlotalotlotlotlot', 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'),
                    col9 = c('asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd', 'alotlotlotlotalotlotlotlotalotlotlotlotalotlotlotlotalotlotlotlotalotlotlotlotalotlotlotlotalotlotlotlotalotlotlotlotalotlotlotlotalotlotlotlotalotlotlotlot', 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'),
                    col_link = c('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page', 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page', 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page')
                ) %>%
                    .[col3 == 'this is url link long',
                      col3 := sprintf(paste0(
                            "<a href=\"%s\" target=\"_blank\" style=\"color:blue\" onmouseover=\"style='",
                            "text-decoration:underline; color:darkblue'\" onmouseout=\"style='",
                            "text-decoration:none; color:blue'\" >%s</a>"), col_link, col3)],
                escape     = FALSE,
                extensions = c('Responsive', 'Buttons'),
                selection    = 'none',
                options    = list(
                    dom        = 'Blftip',
                    pageLength = 3,
                    lengthMenu = c(1, 3),
                    buttons    = I('colvis'),
                    initComplete = JS(
                        "function(settings) {
                            var table=settings.oInstance.api();
                            table.$('td').each(function(){this.setAttribute('title', $(this).html())})}")
                )
            )
        )
    }
)
```

www/app.css

```css
td{
    max-width: 5px; 
    // change as per requirement    
    min-width: 5px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}

td:first-child{
    max-width: 1350px !important; 
    // change as per requirement    
    min-width: 5px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis !important;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

PS: there were n questions + requests concentrated in one question - but, unfortunately, there is no other way. Reason: extensions work separately and on very simple cases. I need to somehow adjust these solutions to the more complex cases above. If at least part of it closes, it will be great!